# JavaStack trace into one doc with logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I couldn't find an answer to my question on stack so I'll ask separetely.
Is there any grok or maybe regexp that merges java stacktrace logs in one?

[image: each line is a separate doc]

I'll provide any additional info needed

Answer (score 1):

The multiline codec [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-multiline.html#_description_184) has an example for handling Java stacktraces:

```
    codec => multiline {
      pattern => "^\s"
      what => "previous"
    }
```